# Directory listing of a network drive by DirDialog in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, network-drive

I am using a DirDialog in wxpython. It works fine for the local drive.
But, it is not able to list the folders in the network drive.
Is there any way to do it ?

I want to select a folder from the network drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me in the wxPython demo on Windows 7, wxPython 2.8.12.1. What version of wxPython are you using? Which OS? There are two other directory controls that you can try too: GenericDirCtrl and MultiDirDialog.

I would recommend creating a little demo app that we can play with too.

Comment: It was actually working, but it takes a lot of time to list them because there are many PC's on the network. However, it only lists some of them. Thanks